# Java GridLayout: new row

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have a JPane GridLayout filled with Buttons (about 30).
I want to go to a new row at specific Points. How can I break to the next line?

I tried to use the LayoutManager, but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: Read the GridLayout API. It tells you how to specify the number of columns (or rows) that you want the grid to contain. You can also read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for a working example. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for Swing basics.

Comment: I actually want to break the Buttons in Groups, and the Groups aren't of the same size (first one with 7, snd with 5, etc) @camickr

Comment: Then you need to use different panels for each group of buttons or you can use the `GridBagLayout` which allows more flexibility. Again, the tutorial has a working example.